# Why do I get "Can't locate loadable object for module" even after installing the module?

Tags: perl, module

Could anyone point me to possible causes of Perl not finding an installed module?

```
$ ll /usr/share/perl5/Unix/Processors.pm
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 3.2K Sep 11 12:39 /usr/share/perl5/Unix/Processors.pm
```

Ok,

```
$ perldoc -l Unix::Processors
/usr/share/perl5/Unix/Processors.pm
```

Ok, but

```
$ perl -MUnix::Processors -e1
Can't locate loadable object for module Unix::Processors in @INC (@INC contains: /usr/lib/cegma /usr/share/mocat/src /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.14.2 /usr/local/share/perl/5.14.2 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.14 /usr/share/perl/5.14 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at -e line 0
Compilation failed in require.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.
```

---

FIXED: I had put the compiled `Processors.so` next to the `.pm` when it should be in the `auto` directory.

Comment: How did you install the module?

Comment: *" I had put the compiled Processors.so next to the .pm when it should be in the auto directory"* You shouldn't "put" any files anywhere. You should *install* the module from the distribution package downloaded from CPAN

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The [`Unix::Processors`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Unix::Processors) module has an XS (C) component that has to be compiled and linked as part of the installation process. The error message `Can't locate loadable object` is referring to this component (a shared library) rather than the `.pm` module file itself

This is a symptom of a wrongly-installed module, and most often happens when the `.pm` file has been simply copied into place instead of being installed properly as described in [perldoc perlmodinstall](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlmodinstall.html). It can also happen if the installation has been *forced*, regardless of any errors in the build and test phases.

Comment: Good answer.  But I used `cpan` on a Mac with homebrew perl, and I got this error.  I had to `use lib(<local directory where cpan put the *.pm>)` to get beyond not finding the pm